# are the twelve stones in Joshua 4 in the Jordan (Joshua 4:9) or in Gilgal (Joshua 4:20)

Tags: contradiction, joshua

Joshua 4:9 says

> Joshua set up the twelve stones that had been in the middle of the Jordan at the spot where the priests who carried the ark of the covenant had stood. And they are there to this day

It says the stones are there to this day but Joshua 4:20 says

> And Joshua set up at Gilgal the twelve stones they had taken out of the Jordan.

Is this not a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

According to some translations, there were two sets of stones.

Joshua 4:9
New Living Translation

> Joshua also set up **another pile of twelve stones** in the middle of the Jordan, at the place where the priests who carried the Ark of the Covenant were standing. And they are there to this day.

Berean Study Bible

> Joshua **also** set up twelve stones in the middle of the Jordan, in the place where the priests who carried the ark of the covenant stood. And the stones are there to this day.

Comment: Good answer: +1. It's interesting that Joshua would set up the first pile of 12 stones "in the middle of the Jordan." I wonder how many people would ever see them as the Jordan River was allowed to again flow? I had a discussion about this with someone recently.